# Надо что бы из реакции бот получал имя человека

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Мне требуется что бы человека ставил реакцию, и в консоль выводилось его имя в формате NAME#0000.
Я нашёл способ как получить id того, кто поставил реакцию, но мне требуется именно никнейм

```
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    channel = await bot.fetch_channel(payload.channel_id)
    mes = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
    emo = payload.emoji
```

Как я могу из `payload` получить тоже самое, что из `ctx.author`.

> ***Спасибо за помощь!***

Comment: по-моему в этом коде вы получаете id сообщения, а не автора

Comment: @Super3283u, вы немного не поняли, этот код получает 3 параметра:
Канал, в котором была получена реакция
Сообщение, на которое была оставлена реакция
Емодзи, которую поставили как реакцию,

И мне надо ЕЩЁ получить имя того, кто поставил реакцию

Comment: а, простите.
может что-то типа "payload.user_id"

Comment: Это как раз id пользователя, я его получить могу, но мне нужен никнейм(

Comment: "payload.user_name", может быть.

Comment: Такого атрибута нет(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from discord import Guild, Member
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot()

async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    # Получаем пользователя
    user: Member = payload.member
    # Отправляем сообщение в консоль с ником пользователя
    print(str(user))
```

P.S Пользователя можно "получить", только если он добавил реакцию и сообщение с реакцией находится в гильдии. [Документация](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_raw_reaction_add#discord.RawReactionActionEvent.member).

Comment: Неа, ошибка

`AttributeError: 'DMChannel' object has no attribute 'guild'`

Comment: @SuperStas0, изменил ответ. Попробуйте также.

Comment: Библиотеки до-подключил. Пишет что переменная `guild` имеет тип None. Из-за этого и ошибка.

Comment: Методом вывода всех переменных я понял в чём проблема: у payload.guild_id тип None

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь то такого как `guild_id` нету, а правильно будет `guild.id`

Comment: @xZartsust, в [документации](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_raw_reaction_add#discord.RawReactionActionEvent), `guild_id`.

Comment: @SuperStas0, если вы не нашли ответ на свой вопрос, то я изменил ответ, я извиняюсь, что можно было сразу получить пользователя.

Comment: @jillstr, спасибо, я ответа не нашёл, пришлось пользоваться id, но теперь буду знать, спасибо!

Comment: @SuperStas0, если ответ вам помог, то можете нажать на галочку возле ответа, отметив его как правильный ;3